# vue async load component on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make a component with nested components in Vue.
The structure can be simplified to

```
ParentComponent.vue
|
|__ ChildComponent.vue
```

Is it possible to get the ChildComponent only when I click a button using @click in the ParentComponent ? I want the component to load its files only after clicking event not just show/hide the component as I am trying to optimize the network usage and the nesting may go a lot deeper.

**EDIT:**
I tried the following code

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <button type="button" @click="isActive=!isActive">SHOW</button>
    <async-component v-show="isActive"></async-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  // The component to load (should be a Promise)
  component: import('./components/ChildComponent.vue'),
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    AsyncComponent
  },
  data(){
    return{
      isActive:false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

but when I click the button it shows the component and when I check the network tab in developer tools it does not show that if fetched anything and the component is already loaded, it just shows/hides it.

Comment: Did you read this: [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)?  Have you tried to work that into a click handler?  Please add code showing what you have tried.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code I was testing, I already read the link and used the snippet at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment, the article is a great resource. I'll highlight the most important part though.

> If you’re a Browserify user that would like to use async components, its creator has unfortunately made it clear that async loading “is not something that Browserify will ever support.” Officially, at least. The Browserify community has found some workarounds, which may be helpful for existing and complex applications. For all other scenarios, we recommend using Webpack for built-in, first-class async support.

In short, you can't if you're using browserify, which since you're using SFCs, I assume you are.

You are also using `v-show`, which uses a display class hidden to hide, so it would be loaded initially even without browserify, so you should be using 'v-if', which removes and adds elements, instead of toggling visibility (you can check that with debug console).

One possibility , however, is code-splitting, where browserify will code split the component into a separate file, but this might not have the result you described either.

example:

```
const Menu = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "signed-in" */ './pages/Menu');
```

Comment: you can see this article for more detail (part 3 especially) https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/08/vue-js-3-ways-code-splitting-webpack/

Comment: After these many years is this answer still up-to-date or do we have something available in Vue 3 now?

Comment: you can use something like: `components: { myComponent: () => iport('MyComponent.vue') }`